# why Java throws a NumberFormatException

Tags: java, exception

I got an exception while parsing a string to byte

```
String Str ="9B7D2C34A366BF890C730641E6CECF6F";

String [] st=Str.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");

byte[]bytes = new byte[st.length];
for (int i = 0; i <st.length; i++) {
 bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(st[i]);
}
```

Comment: When you printed the value of `st` what did you see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the default parse method expects a number in decimal format, to parse hexadecimal number, use this [parse](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
Byte.parseByte(st[i], 16);
```

Where 16 is the base for the parsing.

As for your comment, you are right. The maximum value of Byte is 0x7F. So you can parse it as `int` and perform binary AND operation with `0xff` to get the LSB, which is your byte:

```
bytes[i] = Integer.parseInt(st[i], 16) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: after changing but got this exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"9B" Radix:16

Comment: You're rught - Byte is a signed type, its max value is 0x7F. Use the following instead `bytes[i] = Integer.parseInt(st[i], 16) & 0xFF;` as integer is big enough and binary operation is allowed.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to parse the string as hexadecimal, try this:

```
bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(st[i], 16);
```

The default radix is 10, and obviously `B` is not a base-10-digit.

Comment: after changing but got this exception                                       java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"9B" Radix:16

Answer (score 1):

Java is very picky on signedness, it will not accept values to overflow. Thus, if you parse a Byte and it is larger than 127 (for example, 130 dec or 83 hex) you will get a NumberFormatException. Same happens if you parse an 8 digit hex number as an Integer (or a 16 digit hex number as a Long) and it starts with 8-F. Such values will not be interpreted as negative (two's complement) but as illegal.

If you think that this is anal retentive, I totally agree. But that's Java style.

To parse hex values as two's complement numbers either use a large enough integer type (for example, if you are parsing a Byte use Integer instead and type cast it to a byte later) or -- if you need to parse a Long, split the number in half it is 16 digits, then combine. Here's an example:

```
public static long longFromHex(String s) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (s.length() == 16)
        return (Long.parseLong(s.substring(0,8),16)<<32)|(Long.parseLong(s.substring(8,16),16)&0xffffffffL);
    return Long.parseLong(s, 16);
}
```

Or, to read a Byte, just use Integer instead:

```
public static byte byteFromHex(String s) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
    if (i < 0 || i > 255) throw new IllegalArgumentException("input string "+s+" does not fit into a Byte");
    return (byte)i;
}
```